# My React Native Application closes when I send a Push Notification through Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I started with React Native recently, and it comes up that I had to use Push Notifications to notify all the users when a certain action is triggered,
so alright, I read the Firebase docs, configured the project, installed the dependencies, and I think that I've done everything alright, but my application closes when I try to send any notification to the app, and it's driving me crazy, because I haven't seen any other post with this problem yet, and I simply don't have the less idea on how to correct it, my deadline is coming, I'm gonna let all the configuration files here for you guys, and the actual code that handles the notification, even though it still does just a console.warn() on the message.

The app/build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.watcher"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.+"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0") {
        force = true
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

MainApplication.java:

```
package com.watcher;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import com.evollu.react.fcm.FIRMessagingPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage; // <-- Add this line

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new VectorIconsPackage(),
          new RNFirebasePackage(),
          new FIRMessagingPackage(),
          new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.watcher">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

      <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </service>

      <service
          android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
          </intent-filter>
      </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the actual code that handles the notifications:

```
async checkPermission() {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
        this.receiveToken();
    } else {
        this.requestPermission();
    }
  }

async receiveToken() {
      let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
      if (!fcmToken) {
          fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
          if (fcmToken) {
              await AsyncStorage.setItem('fcmToken', fcmToken);
          }
      }

      return this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage(notif => {
        try {
          console.warn(JSON.stringify(notif));
        } catch(e) {
          console.warn("error trying to handle the message")
        }
      })
    }

    async requestPermission() {
      try {
          await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
          this.receiveToken();
      } catch (error) {
          console.warn('permission rejected');
      }
    }

componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
    this.checkPermission();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.messageListener();
  }
```

Comment: I was just having trouble with bad configuration, so I started a whole new application, and configured firebase from the ground and it got the work done.